# Installing app from Market when it was previously manually installed

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an app that was just released. Prior to release, I had 10 or so testers that helped me test the app and had test versions on their phones. Now I want them to install the app from the Market so they can be some of the first people to (fairly) rate the app.

The problem is, **even after uninstalling the test version of the app**, when trying to get it from the market an error pops up saying that "*there was an error creating your order*." They can't install it. Is there something I or they can do about this?

I told the testers to follow these instructions under **[Troubleshooting Download Issues](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1067233) -> "Download unsuccessful" message**. This did not work.
**Update 1**: Add *Clear Data* for the Market app to the list of things tried.

**Update 2**: It does appear to be something **server-side**. Here's a log:

```
Finsky  : [1] DfeRequest.deliverResponse: Not delivering second response for request=[[ ] https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=com.audia.rta NORMAL 104]
Finsky  : [1] DfeRequest.deliverResponse: Not delivering second response for request=[[ ] https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/rec?c=3&rt=4&doc=com.audia.rta NORMAL 105]
Finsky  : [1] DfeRequest.deliverResponse: Not delivering second response for request=[[ ] https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/rec?c=3&rt=1&doc=com.audia.rta NORMAL 107]
Finsky  : [1] DfeRequest.deliverResponse: Not delivering second response for request=[[ ] https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/rev?doc=com.audia.rta NORMAL 106]
time passes...
Finsky  : [1] CarrierProvisioningAction.run: No need to fetch provisioning from carrier.
Finsky  : [1] GetBillingCountriesAction.run: Skip getting fresh list of billing countries.
time passes...
Volley  : [11] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/purchase
Finsky  : [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorResponse: SERVER: An error occurred while creating your order.
Finsky  : [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=NETWORK_OR_SERVER, code=-1, message=An error occurred while creating your order.
```

Note the `500` response from the server. Oddly or not, *this is the exact output I get if I try to purchase my own app*, but I figured that that was because Google doesn't allow that.

Comment: Uninstall is listed at the bottom of the page there, are you sure everyone tried that (looks like you did in the original question), also did you sign your test app with the release key?

Comment: Yep, the app is uninstalled. Former test versions were signed with debug, but the last few versions were signed with the release key. Changing from one to another hasn't been a problem, at least as long as the app was uninstalled first.

Comment: Since you uninstalled I really can't think of any other client side issue without shooting in the dark.

Comment: Note the update; it's from a server-side 500 error. I don't know what could cause this. I've contacted Google and am waiting to hear back from them, but any other ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Google and not hearing much back from them for a week or two, I and my testers tried again and it started working. I would guess that Google addressed the issue and just didn't tell me about it. (This seems to be consistent with what their support website says they do now.) If anyone else has the same problem I'd advise [contacting Google](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=136601&hl=en) as soon as possible.